# Unable to get 2-way data binding to work

Tags: android, data-binding

I want to bind the value of `EditText`s to a POJO on button click but POJO is null. Following is the code I have written:-

MainActivity:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    ActivityMainBinding binding;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.button)
    public void submit()
    {
        Log.d("myapplication",binding.getUser()); // NullPointerException
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="user"
            type="com.paragkadam.databindingsample.User"/>
    </data>


    <RelativeLayout

        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.paragkadam.databindingsample.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/first_name_edittext"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:hint="First name"
        android:text="@={user.firstName}"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/last_name_edittext"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:hint="Last name"
        android:text="@={user.lastName}"
        android:layout_below="@+id/first_name_edittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/last_name_edittext"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</layout>
```

POJO class User.java :-

```
public class User {
    private String firstName,lastName;

    public User(){}
    public User(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting NullPointerException because you did not set the user value.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main);
        binding.setUser(new User("FirstName","LastName"));
    }
```

Comment: Yes the null pointer exception goes away after calling setUser ()  method.  But my question is - shouldn't the data binding library itself set the value of the User pojo rather than me explicitly calling setUser (). I expect the value of my edittexts to get attached to my pojo user.

Comment: No, Databinding won't set the value by itself. You have to set all the variable value inside `data` tag by yourself through their corresponding setter methods. Once you pass the instance of `User` class through `setUser()` method, It will be attached to the edittext and you can get the text of the edittext in that `User` object.

Comment: So does this mean that I have to set the pojo just once and when the text on the edittexts change, the model is automatically set with updated values?

Answer (score 1):

First of 2 way databinding does not require event just @={} will set variables on every event that performed on view

Second every variable that you write to show in data binding need to set else check for nullchecks
As binding.setuser not called on oncreate method it will be null and binding will call
User.name to set it in text view which will ultimately lead to null pointer

Also check out binding docs
They have set 
@bindable to variables
As well as notified property changed